# Python error : OSError: windll.gdi32.GetPixel failed : return -1

Tags: python, winapi, pyautogui

When I try to run a Python script, it works fine for about 10 minutes and it just stops. Also, I'm using Python 3.7.8. This is my code:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    if pyautogui.pixel(193, 52)[0] == 255:
        print("!")
        click(798, 386)
        time.sleep(1)
```

And this is the error that appears in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\meh\FixedAuto.py", line 15, in <module>
    if pyautogui.pixel(193, 52)[0] == 255:
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 609, in pixel
    raise WindowsError("windll.gdi32.GetPixel failed : return {}".format(color))
OSError: windll.gdi32.GetPixel failed : return -1
```

Comment: Does this happen when your screen goes to sleep?  What are you trying to do here?  There is NO point in doing this once per millisecond.  Your screen won't change any faster than the refresh rate, which is at best about 16ms.

Comment: Ignore my comment about once per millisecond.  Of course I know `time.sleep(1)` sleeps for a full second.

Comment: No, it happens when my screen is turned on and I'm trying to make a bot that detected changes on the screen

Comment: *detects i mean

Comment: `GetPixel` should only fail if the address is outside the current clipping region.  `pyautiogui` called `pyscreeze` which opens a new DC for the desktop, and that shouldn't have a clipping region.  I suggest you just use a `try`/`except` block to catch and ignore the error.

Comment: I think I should learn proper Python knowledge cause this is so confusing. But anyway, I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!